# First child selection on DIV is not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Please find the below JSfiddle link. I am trying to hide the first DIV child (with aaaaaa value) inside the div with the attribute aria-labelledby value.

But i think i made some mistake in the CSS syntax.

Please suggest.

http://jsfiddle.net/5g7ot5qf/

```
div[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-timeout-dialog"]:first-child {
    display:none;
}
```

HTML Code:-

```
<p>I am a <i>strong</i> man. I am a <i>strong</i> man.</p>
<p>I am a <i>strong</i> man. I am a <i>strong</i> man.</p>

<div aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-timeout-dialog">
  hello
      <div>aaaaaa</div>
    <div>X2</div>
    <div>X3</div>
</div
```

Comment: Which div do you want to be gone? aaaaaa one? or all divs inside that `ui-dialog...` div? Or just hello?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `div[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-timeout-dialog"]>div:first-child` as the selector

the >div is added

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/5g7ot5qf/2/

it must be:

```
div[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-timeout-dialog"] div:first-child {
    display:none;
}
```

Have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

Comment: It's not about the `:first-child` but the lack of descendant/child combinator within the selector.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the div with aaaaa content gone use

```
div[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-timeout-dialog"] > div:first-child {
    display:none;
}
```

If you want all div's gone, but hello there use

```
div[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-timeout-dialog"] > div {
    display:none;
}
```

If you want to target divs, use

```
div[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-timeout-dialog"] > div:nth-child(n) {
    display:none;
}
```

Where `n` is the div you want to hide (`n=1,2,3,...`)

EDIT: A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wh3d3dtj/

Comment: IMO it doesn't add anything to Barry's answer. The question is pretty clear `to hide the first DIV child (with aaaaaa value)`.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to use http://caniuse.com/#search=first-of-type

```
div[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-timeout-dialog"] > div:first-of-type
```

Because if you put the text "hello" in some tag

```
<h1>hello</h1>
```

then :first-child will not work

http://jsfiddle.net/kxhk83um/